# Asp.net MVC dual authorization

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, authorization

My question as follows, I have to develop c# dual authorization application using asp.net MVC which means 
when **admin1** log into the application and insert some data to database, such as

```
id  name        age year status     referenceNO

001 maths       12  2018    0       ref1000
002 bio         12  2018    0       ref2000
003 chemistry   12  2018    0       ref3000
```

the system should use this data if this data is approved by second admin called **admin2**, therefore I added this status column, if **admin2** approve this, data status will be 1, then data will be approved. Is this way good for approving inserted data? Or have I got any other way to do this?

And my second question is, the system needs to modify/update id 001's subject name as `Com.maths`. But I need to keep 001 data as it is and need to add another row based on its reference no.

Such as

**Table subject**

```
id  name            year status     referenceNO

001 maths           2018    0       ref1000
002 bio             2018    0       ref2000
003 chemistry       2018    0       ref3000
004 Com.maths       2018    0       ref1000
```

because I already used id 001 for some other table as a foreign key. Such as

**Table Student**

```
id      name    age  subjectID[FK]  

std1    sam     15      001
std2    kal     14      003
std3    misha   12      001
std4    nish    12      002
```

(according to user requirement previously inserted data cannot be changed)

After modifying/updating table subject data by some admin, modification will be approved by another admin. After modification, previously used data cannot be changed. After table subject modification new record for student must use that modified row as `foreign key = 004`.  So what is the best way to do this? I know this question is confusing to understand, but please help me.

Comment: You should ask solution of one particular problem in one question. You also need to share whatever work you have done to solve this problem and tell what issue you are facing with that.

Comment: Assuming I understood, your first question is akin to changing the _status_ of something - like how an _order_ (when shopping online) goes through multiple statuses (from submission to fulfillment/shipping,returns, etc.). The second part sounds like a (separate) "history table" (logs all changes to a record over time). Hth.

Comment: @EdSF Thank for the response. Can u please tell me is this best way to do this? or please tell me how to solve part two. give me sample code to solve my problem

Comment: I gave you an _architectural idea_ - which is what your question is. There is no "code" for that. If the architecture I proposed sounds like what you're after, _you_ have to build it - e.g. a new "history table" that get's populated with the data of some other table _before_ it was modified - so think timestamps, etc. Hth.